# Best algorithm for the Word Ladder puzzle

Tags: optimization, search, algorithm, graphs

What would be the best performing algorithm to solve the Word Ladder problem, in terms of guaranteed finding of the shortest solution in the shortest possible time? Is it BFS, DFS, A*, IDA* or another one? How are these algorithms compared with each other?

For the Word Ladder puzzle, a starting and an ending word of the same length are given. The goal is to convert the starting word to the ending word by changing only on letter at a time. Intermediate words should be valid words. E.g. **silly** => sully => sulky => hulky => hunky => funky => **funny**

Comment: What do you mean by "best performing"? Performing in terms of what?

Comment: Best performing in terms of guaranteed finding of the shortest solution in the shortest possible time

Comment: Ok. Edit your post to include this info! What do you know about this problem and algorithms? For example, can DFS be applied to this problem?

Comment: Ok, the question is edited. I know that BFS and A* can be applied, probably also DFS, but I don't know which one will give a guaranteed optimal solution.